# React Table implement multi select in column Filter

Tags: reactjs

This is the codesandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-wildflower-wfndzv. Here in the Search Box, single field select is working fine, however for multi field select its taking based on the recent name selected. Any idea, how it can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import React, { useState} from "react";

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    // Your data array
  ]);

  const handleMultiSelectChange = (selectedOptions) => {
    setSelectedValues(selectedOptions);
    // Perform filtering based on selected values.
    const filteredData = data.filter((item) =>
      selectedValues.includes(item.field)
    );
    // Update the displayed results with the filtered data.
    // (e.g., setData(filteredData);)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Your other UI components */}
      <MultiSelect
        options={[
          // Your multi-select options
        ]}
        value={selectedValues}
        onChange={handleMultiSelectChange}
        labelledBy={"Select"}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```